# Should it be possible to edit one's profile at discuss.area51?

Tags: support, area-51, profile-page

At the moment it seems like it's not possible to edit your profile at discuss.area51.

Is it intended to be like this?

I don't see why you would have to enter the *main* page to edit your profile. Compared to SO/ meta.SO, it is possible at both pages.

I'm eagerly waiting for: *It's not a bug, it's a feature.* :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't a bug. (:

The Area 51 Discussion Zone is set up as a [child meta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) of Area 51.  This means that your user profile is inherited from the parent site.  As the profile is inherited, it can only be edited from the parent site.  This would be the same on any of the other sites in the network, for example, see your [Fitness and Nutrition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/510/) and its [child meta](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/users/510/) profiles.

SO and MSO are a special case because MSO is the meta for the entire network, not just SO.  That's why the user profile here is not inherited from SO.

Answer (score 4):

> Compared to SO/ meta.SO, it is possible at both pages.

Meta.SO is a *special* type of meta site that's a hybrid between a regular meta site and a full SE site, because of the various responsibilities of MSO.

A better comparison would be [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) and [Meta.Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com). As you can see, you cannot edit your profile on Meta.Programmers, nor on any other per-site meta. The reason for this is that they are two facets of one "person", and are the same user, as they are on A51 and Discuss.A51.